# What is the difference between flip() and flipud() in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is the difference between `flip()` and `flipud()` in NumPy?

Both functions do the same things so which one should I use?

Comment: They are not exactly the same, but you can use either one. The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) explains the difference.

Comment: Look at the [source].  Neither is complicated.  `flip` on the 1st dimension is just `m[::-1, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both functions do the same things

That's only true for 1-D arrays.

For N-D arrays, `np.flipud(a)` is only the same as `np.flip(a, axis=0)`. There's another convenience function `np.fliplr(a)` that corresponds to `np.flip(a, axis=1)`.

---

[`np.flip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html#numpy.flip) is required if you need to flip dimension 3 or higher, e.g., the 3rd dimension (axis 2):

```
np.flip(a, axis=2)
```

Or to flip multiple dimensions at once, e.g., the 1st and 3rd dimensions (axis 0 and 2):

```
np.flip(a, axis=(0, 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

flipud can only flip an array along the vertical axis and flip will flip along a given axis. Very similiar.